# How UPDATE and check for duplicate key

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE update_logo_id_in_feeds(feed_id INT)
          BEGIN
            UPDATE feeds SET logo_id =
            (
              SELECT image_id
              FROM posts
              WHERE id =
              (
                 SELECT post_id 
                 FROM feed_posts 
                 WHERE priority=
                    (
                       SELECT MAX(feed_posts.priority)
                       FROM feed_posts
                       WHERE feed_posts.feed_id = feed_id
                    )
                 AND feed_posts.feed_id = feed_id
              )
            )
            WHERE feeds.id = feed_id;
          END
```

I have such procedure. It call when new `post` add to `feed` (write in pivot table `feed_posts`) and set `logo_id`. I have 100 `feeds` and when I add one `post` to 100 `feeds` - all 100 `feeds` have same `logo_id`. How check when UPDATE if other `feeds` with such `logo_id` exists and don't update?

Comment: It's a bad idea to have an input parameter name that is the same as a table column name.